# How to dynamically create list of days

Tags: angular, ngfor

I'm trying to print days from an array which structure looks like as follows.

```
form:[
    {
      SUN:{
        name:'sunday',
        task:[]
      }
    },
    {
      MON:{
        name:'monday',
        task:[]
      }
    }
  ]
```

by using the above array I want to create a form dynamically, which consist of day name and it's tasks;

I have already tried with the following code snippets.

```
<div *ngFor="let item of workingHourForm;let i =index">

  {{item.SUN.name}} // dynamically change SUN --> MON .....
</div>
```

But it's showing only 1 result.

Expected output:

Sunday      : Tasks 1 Task 2  
Monday      : Tasks 1 Task 2

Have a look at: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-cereff?file=src/app/app.component.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Angular's [KeyValuePipe](https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe) to iterate over the object and print the tasks:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of workingHourForm">
  <div *ngFor="let x of item | keyvalue">
    {{ x.key }}: <span class="task" *ngFor="let task of x.value.tasks">{{task}}</span>
  </div>
</div>
```